Motivation behind vector spaces from linear systems and other perspectives
I am currently trying to understand how the motivation for vector spaces arises from solving systems of linear equations. As per my understanding, systems of linear equations can be reduced to a problem (for example) whereby we have to find a linear combination such that $\vec{a}x_1 + \vec{b}x_2 + \vec{c}x_3 = \vec{d}$
However, because the $a, b, c, d$ entities in problems of this form need not necessarily be column vectors (eg. they can be polynomials, functions, or anything that can be linearly combined), then we generalise, moving from studying the effects of linear combinations in only $\mathbb{R}^n$ to studying them in any space of 'linearly combine-able objects', and we call this space a vector space
I assume this is why vector spaces come built in with a definition of addition and multiplication — otherwise there would be no way to make linear combinations within the space. I also assume this is why conditions like associativity of addition etc. are imposed on vector spaces — so linear combinations in the spaces share the same properties as those in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is this a valid motivation for the idea of a vector space from the perspective of systems of linear equations? What are the other useful motivations / reasons / perspectives for construction for a vector space?

Another motivation for vector spaces comes from differential equations. Many situations in applications of mathematics involve equations of the form
$$
a(x){d^2y\over dx^2}+b(x){dy\over dx}+c(x)y=0
$$
which we call a homogeneous linear differential equation. The set of all solutions to such an equation is closed under addition, and under multiplication by real numbers, and satisfies properties involving commutativity, associativity, additive identity element, additive inverses, distributivity; in short, the set forms a vector space, so one can use all the power of Linear Algebra to study these differential equations.

I see - so this problem (and I assume others in different applications) all shared the same property of solutions to linear systems that the solutions are closed under addition etc. - thus it makes sense to generalise such sets that obey all the properties you mentioned into vector spaces. That way, if we make a finding about vector spaces in general, the finding applies to solution sets of homogeneous linear differential equations, systems of linear equations, as well as any other 'similar' problem.

Let $F$ be a field, let $p$ be a polynomial with coefficients in $F$. Then $p$ may or may not have any zeros in $F$, but it is certain to have zeros in an appropriate extension field $K$ of $F$. It's easy to show that $K$ is a vector space over $F$, and this view of extension fields as vector spaces is very useful in the study of solutions of polynomial equations.
